# How to send TCP queries for unknown IP of embedded system?

Tags: java, android, embedded, serial-port

I need to make Android application which can send TCP queries to an embedded RS-232 system (connected to a router).

Unfortunately, no IP address was given because each embedded system has a different IP address.

To learn the IP Address, an android device (tablet/smartphone) must connect to the local wireless network and acquire the address of the embedded system. The local network also has a public IP address which enables the embedded system to communicate with the outside world.

My task is to send queries to the embedded system and get replies from it.  The protocol is RS-232 for both input and output.

Please, give me an idea of where to start. Thank you.

Comment: "Embedded system" could mean anything. What's the protocol for the discovery? You got to have that spec at least, no?

Answer (score 2):

Scan the network for the open port if there are no zero config options.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the range of mac addresses the devices use you should be able to filter them out using ARP.

Answer (score 1):

In case you can control both ends you can use [multicast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast#IP_multicast) and save the discovery step.
Alternatively you can use [dns-sd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_configuration_networking), but again the embedded system should be aware of it.
At the end, if none of the above options are possible you should scan the network as mentioned in other answer, but if DHCP is used you will never know if the address you obtained is still valid.

Comment: Thank you. But how can I connect & scan network programatically?

Comment: Try to open the connection to every address x every port, if succeeds you found it

Comment: But can I get list of all addresses?

Comment: from your address and the mask

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about on the same network you could use a UDP broadcast which is picked up by the device which contains the remote ip, which then sends a response to the android handset with it's own tcp ip address.